# Verify client's script from creator's site in PHP

Tags: php, dns, client, verify, ownership

I made a website for someone and want to retain ownership to the site even if the client has the script, just like verifying if you purchased a script and are using it on just one domain.

I want to make sure that one domain cannot share a script's purchase code with another domain. How do I do this?

Ex: A - developer; B - client who bought script; Ba - B's purchase code and cannot be used by another (C, D, E, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

The ownership of the domain is identified by the Authoritative Name server access. Person who has access to its Authoritative name server and is able to change the Authoritative name server has full ownership of that domain.

For the restriction on the script to be used with certain domain, your script must validate the access token from your server, every time it runs. But if someone has access to the code, they can always bypass it by making changes in the code.

I hope this clarifies.